# Colour maths: effect of transparent black overlay on lightness

Tags: css, colors, sass

I've been playing with [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) recently, and have found the [`darken`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#darken-instance_method) function, which works by reducing the HSL "lightness" component of a colour by a given amount, to be quite useful.  At one point I ended up trying to convert from a semi-transparent black overlay to an equivalent `darken` application in the following context:

- Container background: `$color` (any colour)

  - Content background: `darken($color, 20%)` (20% darker)

    - Heading background: `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)` (20% opacity black overlay)

I had thought I could replace the heading background with `darken($color, 36%)` (80% lightness × 80% lightness = 64% lightness), however that is much darker.  The value that produces visually similar results is around 25%.

Obviously 100% opacity equates to 0% lightness, and 0% opacity equates to 100% lightness, but between there the scale seems to be linear for transparency and... not for lightness (due to darken basically subtracting from the lightness component).

So, my question is how can a translucent black overlay be converted to an equivalent reduction in lightness?  Is it even possible?

Here's a fiddle with an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/R7aYP/2 - I'm interested in finding a formula to work out `.box.three`'s darkness percentage from `.box.two`'s opacity.

#### Edit:

@cimmanon mentioned that the [`mix`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#mix-instance_method) function can be used to create the same effect with `mix($color, black, 80%)` - I'm still interested to know if there's a relationship between this mixing and darken/lighten.

#### Edit:

I realised this is actually pretty trivial, the `darken` function simply subtracts the absolute value, e.g.:

```
darken(blue, 20%) = hsl(hue(blue), saturation(blue), lightness(blue) - 20)
```

Whereas a mix with black is a percentage reduction, so:

```
mix(blue, black, 80%) = darken(blue, lightness(blue) * 0.2)
```

And an obligatory fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R7aYP/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you want to use instead is `mix()`.  Since your black is 80% transparent (20% opaque), you'll need to adjust the weight of the mixture in favor of the first color.

```
.foo {
    background: mix(blue, black, 80%);
}
```

Comment: That definitely does it!  I'm still interested to see if there's a relationship between mixing with black/white and darken/lighten, so I'll leave it open for now.

Comment: Your original question was answered, you have the information you need to investigate further.  If you would like to ask a different question, then ask a different question.

Comment: You have provided a functional alternative to a translucent black overlay, however my question, "How can a translucent black overlay be converted to an equivalent reduction in lightness", is yet to be answered.