# How can I create a mixin that will output an expected color, but at a slightly lower opacity?

Tags: css, sass, hex, mixins, rgba

I've found that by using a slightly transparent version of a grayscale color on text makes the text appear more crisp on the screen.

For example, the following:

```
color: lighten(#A2A2A2, 11.5%)
color: rgba(#A2A2A2, 0.7);
background-color: #F6F6F6;
```

The output of those colors is the same as `color: #BBBBBB` on that same background, only [where supported with RGBa] it appears more crisp on the screen. And to create a fallback for browsers that don't support RGBa you'll notice I'm using the lighten function. I'm hoping this all makes sense...

To make things easier on myself I've created a simple mixin that automates the output:

```
@mixin rgbaColor($color, $opacity, $lightness) {
  color: lighten($color,$lightness);
  color: rgba($color, $opacity);
}
```

Problem is, it takes *forever* to determine what the hex code should be to make the text appear to be #BBB, when really it's another color at 70% opacity. In addition to that creating the fallback is even more difficult - it wasn't easy figuring out that lightening #A2A2A2 by 11.5% would output #BBB. All in all it's effort is greater than it's worth. **So my question is**, if I add the background color and the *expected color* (so in this case, #BBB) in to that mixin, is there any way that SASS can calculate what the darker color at 70% opacity would be to get the expected visual output color?

Reading back, this is a bit confusing. So this is *kind of* what I'm hoping to do:

`@include rgbaColor(#BBB, #F6F6F6, 0.7)` *where #BBB is the expected visual color, #F6F6F6 is the background color, and 0.7 is the opacity at which I'd like the text set.*

Using a mixin something like this:

```
@mixin rgbaColor($visualColor, $backgroundColor, $opacity) {
  // Crazy math to figure it out...
}
```

To output this:

```
color: lighten(#A2A2A2, 11.5%)
color: rgba(#A2A2A2, 0.7);
```

I completely understand if this is not possible, but if it is it will be extremely handy for me. Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2204/how-to-calculate-other-colors-with-the-same-perceived-lightness-as-a-given-gray

Comment: You're welcome! I didn't expect to find it. Really cool stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Colour maths: effect of transparent black overlay on lightness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403702/colour-maths-effect-of-transparent-black-overlay-on-lightness)